# Find all records in a table from a specific date using system tables in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to write a query which will return table_name,count (Record insert and records updated) and date_of_operation from the entire database, using system tables.

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken you are out of luck on this one, unless you record a date in your tables. There is no such date recorded automatically. You can set it up if you want to do it in the future, but not for past updates. See Temporal tables for how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS cache
```

Is as close as you get to some 'logging' built into SQL, but it only holds queries executed that are still stored in the cache.

Which means - it could store queries executed from 1 year to 1 minute ago.

You might also want to take a look at this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142544/get-all-the-queries-executed-in-the-last-week-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You might look at Change Data Capture.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

"Change data capture records insert, update, and delete activity that is applied to a SQL Server table."

It's not using system tables, but it might get you the logging you're looking for.